# Can we plant Peepal tree at home as a bonsai

Tags: belief

Can we plant `Peepal Tree` at home as a Bonsai, as every one know that Peepal Tree gives oxygen 24 hrs, So is it good to plant it at home or balcony.

If no, then why?

Comment: The Bonsai are mainly for artistic purpose.If your main concern is oxygen or decoration ,then i think this isn't a right place for the question.You can ask whether we can worship  trees in Bonsai form at home etc.

Comment: `BG 10.26 - अश्वत्थः सर्ववृक्षाणां - Among all trees, I am Peepal`!

Comment: Related - http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3678/is-it-ok-to-uproot-peepal-tree/3682#3682

Answer (score 4):

Peepal(Aswatha) and Banyan  are the most sacred trees among Hindus.As per [this](http://www.astrojyoti.com/vastutreesnplants.htm) website:

> Banyan and Pipal (Aswatha) are sacred trees; they should usually only
>   be planted near a temple or at a sacred place.

So,planting it in one's home or balcony **is usually not recommended**.

However,planting of Tulasi and Bilwa are allowed in home and recommended.And both are considered holy among Hindus.

NoTe:I will try to search if i can find more specific instructions from Scriptures ,but you can certainly rely on that site as its easily one among the best "Hinduism" websites.

Comment: But its is said that we should pour water to Peepal Tree early morning.

Comment: @Mongrel Yes,Peepal is worshiped like Gods,ladies who don't have children are told to go round it.Offering of water,milk are also done .But those are usually done  in temple premises not in home.